# Django complex filter by foreign key in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

**Using Django 1.6**

This is part of my model.

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    discount_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    discount_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    discount_subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(Subcategory)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Whole of **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from uygulama.models import *

admin.site.register([Company, Discount, Store, Category, City, Subcategory])
```

What I want:

I am adding `Discount` record. Meanwhile I select one parent category and I want to list all this parent category's subcategory. But I am getting this. When page open no selected category and listing all subcategories:

[image]

But I want to list only selected category's subcategories in `Discount` adding page. Not in `Subcategory` page.

Comment: I got this link ,, it might help you http://www.s-block.com/blog/2012/11/28/django-chained-select-box/

Comment: Can you post the answer if you got how to solve this? I found this two packages [django-clever-selects](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-clever-selects/0.6.9) and [django-selectable0select2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-selectable-select2/0.4.0) relevant.